# Inserting elements into list (without using Python's list.insert(index, item) function)

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to insert element into a list at a position before a particular index. Example,

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

enter the index = 3
enter the item = 7
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,7,4,5]
```

Since the input index is 3, python will append the new item at position index-1 which is 2.

I have tried something like but the output seemed a little off:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

indexInput = int(input("Enter the index: "))
itemInput = int(input("Enter the item: "))

for i in mylist:
    new_slot = indexInput -1
    new_length = len(mylist) + 1
    if i == new_slot:
         mylist[i] = item
         mylist.append(mylist[i])
print(mylist)
```

I know about the insert() function in python but I'm not allowed to use it so i had to code it the long way. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use list slicing:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

indexInput = int(input("Enter the index: "))
itemInput = int(input("Enter the item: "))

if indexInput<0:
  indexInput = len(mylist)+indexInput+1

mylist = mylist[:indexInput] + [itemInput] + mylist[indexInput:]
print(mylist)
# for index 3 and item 7 => [1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5]
# for index -2 and item 6 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

Explanation:

```
list[start:end:step] => list items from index [start] to index [end-1] with a step of 1
if start is not given, 0 is assumed, if end is not given, it goes all the way to the end of the list, if step is not given, it assumes a step of 1
In my code I wrote:
mylist = mylist[:indexInput] + [itemInput] + mylist[indexInput:]
for indexInput=3 and itemInput=7
mylist = mylist[:3] + [7] + mylist[3:]
mylist[:3] => mylist from 0 (start not given), to 3-1, step of 1 (step not given)
list1 + list2 => a list that contains elements from list1 and list2
mylist[:3] + [7] => [...elements of mylist[:3]..., 7]
mylist[3:] => mylist from 3, to len(mylist)-1 (end not given), step of 1 (step not given)
```

If you want to do it the long way, here's a solution:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

indexInput = int(input("Enter the index: "))
itemInput = int(input("Enter the item: "))
if indexInput<0:
      indexInput = len(mylist)+indexInput+1
leftSide = []
rightSide = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
  if i<indexInput:
    leftSide.append(mylist[i])
  elif i>indexInput:
    rightSide.append(mylist[i])
  else:
    leftSide.append(itemInput)
    leftSide.append(mylist[i])

mylist = leftSide + rightSide
print(mylist)
# for index 3 and item 7 => [1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5]
# for index -2 and item 6 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for the explanation. But if my index were to be negative index, the code won't work.

Comment: @Maxxx use the `abs()` function to get the absolute value of the number in this case, check my updated my answer.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, but if negative index were to be used, it means the program will start at the end of the list just like list[-2] = item

Comment: If you use `abs()` it won't start at the end, if the user enters `-2`, `abs(-2) = 2`. or do you want it to start from the end?

Comment: in this case, yes since we are dealing with index, if the index is positive, we start from the beginning of the list and if the index is negative, we start at the end of the list. sorry for the trouble once more.

Comment: @Maxxx I updated my answer to support negative indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

indexInput = int(input("Enter the index: "))
itemInput = int(input("Enter the item: "))

for idx, val in enumerate(mylist):
    if idx == indexInput:
        mylist = mylist[:idx] + [itemInput] + mylist[idx:]

print(mylist)
```

Hope it can help you, just use `enumerate` function to get `mylist` index

Comment: @Mr Geek 's answer is better than mine

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
inputIndex = 3
inputItem = 7
temp = 0

for i in range(len(list)):#continuously swap your elements until you reach the end
    if(i == len(list) - 1): # if you're at the end, swap and add the temp to the end
        temp = list[i]
        list[i] = inputItem
        list.append(temp)
    elif(i >= inputIndex):
        temp = list[i]
        list[i] = inputItem
        inputItem = temp

print(list)
```

This is probably what you're looking for, if this is for an assignment where you're not allowed to use `insert` then I am assuming you probably aren't allowed to use slicing